# Combine Date and Time

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, exception, datetime-parsing

I need to combine date and time  and insert into one datetime row.

Here is my code:

```
 DateTime Headlinedate;

 try
 {
     DateTime date = Convert.ToDateTime(txtHeadlinedate.Text.Trim(), Ci);
     string timestr = DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss tt");
     DateTime combinedDate = date.Add(TimeSpan.Parse(timestr));
     Headlinedate = combinedDate;

 }
 catch {
     Headlinedate = DateTime.Now;
 }
```

I'm getting exception :

> Input string was not in a correct format

Comment: When you debug it, what is the format of `date` ?

Comment: `DateTime combinedDate = date.Add(DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay);` instead of parsing `TimeSpan` from string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you get this exception of the first line of code, you'll have to make sure that the content of `txtHeadlinedate` is valid and parse it accordingly.

If the error comes from the call to `TimeSpan.Parse`, the following version should fix the problem:

```
DateTime date = Convert.ToDateTime(txtHeadlinedate.Text.Trim(), Ci);
Headlinedate = date.Add(DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay);
```

Comment: To make absolutely sure you get no time-of-day component from the first line (the conversion of the text string), you could add a `.Date` to the end of the first line.

Answer (score 2):

TimeSpan can't parse "tt". Use DateTime to parse it, or instead use HH:mm format to get 24-hour value of hours and remove tt part from your format. Then TimeSpan will be able to parse it. For example:

```
DateTime date = Convert.ToDateTime(txtHeadlinedate.Text.Trim(), Ci);
string timestr = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss");
DateTime combinedDate = date.Add(TimeSpan.Parse(timestr));
Headlinedate = combinedDate;
```

Comment: It's not really necessary to convert "now" into a time string and then convert the string back to a `TimeSpan`.

Comment: Right, which makes is essentially the same as ybo's answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
date.Hour=DateTime.Now.Hour;
date.Minute=DateTime.Now.Minute;
date.Second=DateTime.Now.Second;
```

Comment: that's a rather poor answer why are you doing 3 steps when you can do it in one step..?

Comment: And this is relevant with this question because..?

Comment: First, you shouldn't read the `Now` property more than one time. The clock may change, so if it's `09:59:59` when you read the first part, and `10:00:00` when you read the last part, you might get a mix like `09:00:00` which is far from the true "now". Also if your `date` identifier is supposed to be a `DateTime` value, you can mutate it like you do. The properties in question are `get`-only (no setters). Downvoted.

Answer (score 0):

Use `DateTime.TryParse` and pass your `txtHeadlinedate.Text.Trim()` value

```
DateTime.TryParse(String, IFormatProvider, DateTimeStyles, DateTime)
```

And for adding timespan value
either use

```
DateTime myDate = ExistingTime.Date.AddHours(hh).AddMinutes(min);
```

or
// Calculate what day of the week is 36 days from this instant.(like below)

```
System.DateTime today = System.DateTime.Now; System.TimeSpan duration = new System.TimeSpan(36, 0, 0, 0); System.DateTime answer = today.Add(duration);
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess this should work

```
DateTime Headlinedate;
try
         {
             DateTime date = Convert.ToDateTime(txtHeadlinedate.Text.Trim(), Ci);
             string timestr = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:MM:ss");// here is the solution
             DateTime combinedDate = date.Add(TimeSpan.Parse(timestr));
             Headlinedate = combinedDate;

         }
         catch {
             Headlinedate = DateTime.Now;
         }
```

Comment: Don't use `"MM"` for minutes; it's _months_. It wasn't the purpose to get the date part of `Now`. It really isn't necessary to use `ToString` here.

Answer (score -1):

```
DateTime date = Convert.ToDateTime(txtHeadlinedate.Text.Trim(), Ci);    
DateTime combinedDate = new DateTime(date.Year, date.Month, date.Day, DateTime.Now.Hour, DateTime.Now.Minute, DateTime.Now.Second);
```

Answer (score -1):

This works!

```
DateTime _dateOnly = DateTime.Now;
DateTime _timeOnly = DateTime.Now;

public DateTime Combined { get; set; }

      public DateTime DateOnly
        {
            get { return _dateOnly.Date; }
            set
            {
                _dateOnly = value.Date;
                Combined = DateOnly.Add(TimeOnly.TimeOfDay);
            }
        }

        public DateTime TimeOnly
        {
            get { return _timeOnly.ToLocalTime(); }
            set
            {
                _timeOnly = value.ToLocalTime();
                Combined = DateOnly.Add(TimeOnly.TimeOfDay);
            }
        }
```